# SVN says file is in version control when it isnt

Tags: svn

I run 'svn status' and I get

```
?      app/views/ad_report
```

But when I try to run 'svn add app/views/ad_report', it says it's already in version control, but status just said it isn't.

```
svn: warning: 'app/views/ad_report' is already under version control
```

There is a folder with the same name in a different path, 'app/views/backend/ad_report', but there are a lot of same folder names, but different path in this repo, and all those have been added.

Is svn getting these two folders mixed up? How do I get around this?

Comment: Did you try `svn cleanup` ? Also, you may get better answers at superuser.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you move the folder from `app/views/ad_report` to `app/views/backend/ad_report` before? If that's true, did you copy the `.svn` folder with it? That's where it might be coming from. Either delete it or move it back and use the `svn move` command to move it directly in the repo.

Comment: Doh, I did copy that folder. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to try running this script and remove all the svn files and then re-add the folder to your repo.

```
find ./ -name ".svn" | xargs rm -Rf
```